# PHP OOP beginner - what is $this->object->method() or anything with 2 arrow ->

Tags: php, oop

Usually I understand about `$this->method()`  or `$this->property`   or `$object->method()`  or `$object->property`

but sometimes I see `$this->$object->method()`.  or anything that has two arrow `..->.. -> ..`

**What does it mean?**

Comment: Look above that line. Does `$object` have a value

Comment: It just means the property of a class returns an instance of yet another class that also has a method... this can go on and on.

Comment: Whatever it is, `$this->object->method()` is not the same as `$this->$object->method()`. Read more about [PHP Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and about [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (regarding `$object`)

Comment: You have to have a look here also (PHP Versions): http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling

Answer (score 3):

This means that `$object` is a variable that holds a field name.

Example:

```
class Foo 
{
    public $bar = 'some string';
}

$foo = new Foo();
$field = 'bar';
echo $foo->$field; // prints 'some string'
```

Then, if a `method()` is called on that field, it means that the field is also an object.

Comment: Also called variable variables http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Nice, but can you also explain the diff. PHP Version mostly PHP before 7 and after 7. `$this->$object->method()`  http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling :-)

Comment: I'm not aware of behavior differences of variable variables between PHP 5 and 7, not in this simple case anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/769651)

**Example 1:**
Here we are creating object `(new X())` and invoking public function `test()` which returns current class object (i.e. `X` class) and then i am invoking `newTest()` function over that object.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
class X
{
    public $x=0;
    public function test($x)
    {
        $this->x=$x;
        return $this;
    }
    public function newTest()
    {
        print_r($this);
    }
}
(new X())
        ->test(10)
        ->newTest();
```

**Example 2:** Here we are creating class `Y` object and setting class `Z` object in class `Y` with and then calling method `test()`

```
$object= new Y(new Z());
$object->test();
```

When we are invoking function `test` there calling `$this->{$object}->in_z();` is equal to calling `$this->myNewObject->in_z();` which outputs `in_z`

```
class Y
{
    public $myNewObject=null;
    public function __construct($object)
    {
        $this->myNewObject=$object;
    }
    public function test()
    {
        $object="myNewObject";
        $this->{$object}->in_z();
    }
}

class Z
{
    public function in_z()
    {
        echo __FUNCTION__;
    }
}
$object= new Y(new Z());
$object->test();
```

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for an explanation and not just a demo/popped in code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for reminding it had put the explaination.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine an object Teacher

Object Teacher have a method called : teach()
If you are using the Teacher object, you can call $this->teach();

Now imagine you have another Object ClassRoom that have a property "Teacher" which is a teacher object.

If you are using the classroom object, you can now call $this->teacher->teach() and it will invoke the teach() method of the teacher Object.

Comment: This is not what he/she/it asks for.

Answer (score 2):

When you have Object of an Object. 
**For example:**

```
class Test{
    private $obj;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->obj = (object) array('name' => 'foo');
    }

    public function printObj(){
        echo ($this->obj->name);
    }
}

$testClassObject = new Test();
$testClassObject->printObj();
```

See how its works. First of all, In the code there is an Object (stdClass Object) and Suppose in this class if there is a method called `myAnotherTest()` which returns stdClass type Object (Like DB data objects) then you can use `$testClassObject->myAnotherTest()->result->name;`. You can chain as much as you want, **see following code carefully, see output too**

```
class Test{
    private $obj;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->obj = (object) array('name' => 'foo');
    }

    public function printObj(){
        echo ($this->obj->name);
    }

    public function myAnotherTest(){
        return $this->obj;
    }
}

$testClassObject = new Test();
$testClassObject->printObj();
echo "<br>No testing another method<br>";
echo $testClassObject->myAnotherTest()->name; //see this you will be clear
```

Note: If you have another object pointed by `name` instead of a string value as `foo`, you could use like
`echo $testClassObject->myAnotherTest()->name->subObject;`

```
$Object->method()->object->object->value................
$Object->object->value.....................
etc...
```